# VB Textbox input to single

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I need a line of code that will help me input a graphical input from a textbox to single for the calculation such as "X * X" for a quadratic as the code below gives the error System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format

```
Dim y As Single
y = Convert.ToSingle(txtY.Text)
Chart1.Series("plot1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
```

i also tried

```
Dim v As String
v = txtY.Text
Dim y As Single
Single.TryParse(v, y)
 Chart1.Series("plot1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
```

but it didnt work properly so i can assume i made an error somewhere within the code. i need any way to get a textbox input to a single for a calculation

Comment: `Single.Parse` and `Single.TryParse` expect a number represented as a string. `X * X` is not a number (and nor would be `X`). You seem to be looking for math formula parsing.

Comment: thank you! any idea what i could use instead? i found NCalc but my VB doesnt recognise it and i dont know which exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not concerned about with exponents, constants, or functions (i.e. basic math operations) then you can leverage the DataTable's Compute method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8

Here is an example:

```vb
Dim table = New DataTable()
Dim y = table.Compute(txtY.Text, Nothing)
Chart1.Series("plot1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0487BD)

Comment: i tried this method earlier and i get the error "System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [x]." do you know if ive maybe made an error somehow?

Comment: @RalsieGeaff what is it that you are trying to pass? Is it a valid expression or did you try to literally pass `X * X`?

Comment: yeah im trying to get a graphical input like x*x to be the y in my calculations, so the end user can choose what graph will be output. have i gone about this incorrectly?

Comment: You will need to pass the literal values for X. This can be done like the following if you know that X will be a valid Single (using either a NumericUpDown or TryParse): `Dim y = table.Compute($"{x} * {x}", Nothing)`

Comment: is there a way to get that input from a textbox at all? i would rather the end user could edit it whilst it was running

Comment: You can do the same thing, only replacing the value before it is passed to the expression: `Dim y = table.Compute(txtY.Text.Replace("x", txtX.Text).Replace("X", txtX.Text), Nothing)`

Comment: as i have a line of code of  `Dim n As Integer
        n = txtX.Text
        For x As Integer = -n To n Step 1` do you know how i could make it loop so that every value of n is input rather than the one integer